# Leightweight CMS for frontend developers

Tags: content-management-system, backend

I am looking for a CMS which allows me to code normal html but also define "fields" like {{header}} for example, which can later be managed inside an admin panel for easy customisation for the customer.

The basic idea is to be as free as possible as frontenddeveloper but also having a nice backend where the customer can edit the content (images, text) easely without touching the code.

Wordpress may offer this possibilities but is clearly an overkill. Grav couldn't fullfill my needs either.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 2):

Personally I love CraftCMS - basically it has no frontend logic, but allows you to create very convinient forms for the admin / content creators.

I always dislike having to write your own modules / plugins for most cms systems to add your own 'Slideshow' etc. - it takes way too long. Besides the CMS Backends tend to confuse the customers.

In craft you basically create the forms for the content types in the backend and create a really simple and intuitive backend for your customer that way. It comes with very handy features.
Everything the customer doesn't need to change - you can simply write in html. The amount of extra code between a craft cms page and pure html page is minimal making your life as frontend developer much easier.

Comment: +100 For CraftCMS. Best CMS for developers and users alike, with no restrictions upon how you write your front-end code.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the [Gantry](http://gantry.org/) framework. You can use the framework inside WordPress, Joomla or Grav and it basically adds a templating system where the developer builds the modular components (e.g. slider, header, video); You code those into a template, and then parameterise the fields you want to open to the user; the user drags that component where they want it in the layout builder; they can enter data to populate those fields.

I think Gantry is one of the best examples I've seen of empowering the content admin while not hindering the developer, and it sounds like what you are looking for. I would recommend downloading the helium skeleton 
theme since its pre-populated with examples for you to understand.

And in terms of being 'light weight' I would recommend you combine that with Grav since it is more light weight and simpler to work with than the others.

Comment: The OP is clearly not asking for a framework, stating that he'd like the freedom to create the frontend. Gantry is an absolute horror and would provide administrators with exactly what the OP has said he doesn't want them to have; admins should be able to work with content and not be able to anything else!